# Python write error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, python-3.x, fwrite

I have a Python script which prints 3 values `x, y, z` as follows -
`1`,`2`,`WELCOME_TO_ROS`

Now I want to write these values to a header file in the following format -

`#define WELCOME_TO_ROS 1,2, "WELCOME_TO_ROS"`

My attempt so far -

`f.write('#define %s %d, %d, "%s"') % (z, x, y, z)`

What should be the correct format? I am getting the following error -

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Comment: put all the formating `% tuple` inside the parentheses next to the string

Comment: Yep @PRMoureu is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create tuple

```
tp = (1,2,"WELCOME_TO_ROS")
```

Write to header file with file handle f

```
f.write('#define {2} {0},{1}, "{2}"'.format(tp[0], tp[1], tp[2]))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you